# Как в Qt создать кастомный элемент для QListView\QListWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtcreator

Необходимо создать список виджетов (большой), в каждом виджете списка имеются кнопки\чекбоксы и т.д. как это сделать правильно? сейчас имеется костыльная реализация через установку виджета в список функцией - `QListWidget::setItemWidget(QListWidgetItem *item, QWidget *widget);` Но этот вариант весьма тормозной.

Элементы списка выглядят примерно так:
[image: ListItemWidget]

Comment: Тормозной он возможно из-за того что список длинный. А отображается наверняка не весь список, а только небольшая его часть

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала попробуйте банально заменить `QListView` на `QVBoxLayout` в  `QScrollArea`. Вполне возможно, что стандартные механизмы Qt самостоятельно справятся с большим количеством виджетов, там вроде бы есть механизмы, позволяющие не рисовать невидимые элементы, а `setItemWidget` вполне может их игнорировать.

Если не поможет - попробуйте использовать Model-View. Создайте модель, которая для каждой строки будет хранить отображающий её виджет без родителя и отрисовывайте её в методе `paint` делегата при помощи `QWidget::render`, примерно так:

```
QSize sizeHint(const QStyleOptionViewItem& option, const QModelIndex& index) const override{
    auto data  = index.data().value<RowStruct>();
    return ret = data.widget->sizeHint();
}

void paint(QPainter* painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem& option, const QModelIndex& index) const override{
    auto data  = index.data().value<RowStruct>();
    auto point  = painter->deviceTransform().map(option.rect.topLeft());
    data.widget->render(painter,point, QRect(QPoint{}, option.rect.size()), QWidget::RenderFlag::DrawChildren);
 }
```

Само по себе большое количество виджетов тут не проблема - главное, чтобы они не отрисовывались все сразу, что обеспечивается `View`. На крайний случай можно вручную следить за отображаемыми виджетами и удалять лишние.

Основная проблема - это редактирование. Сделать сам виджет доступным для редактирования не проблема - достаточно возвращать его из `createEditor` делегата, назначив родителя. Но триггеры редактирования в Q**View - это двойной щелчок мышью и подобные. Возможно, поможет переопределение `event` или `eventFilter`  делегата - я не пробовал.